# Conditional formatting as a Java float

Tags: java, excel, floating-point, conditional-formatting

I would like to cause Excel to format a number as Java formats a float, or at least similarly.  In particular, I would like to have it display an arbitrary number of digits to the RIGHT of the decimal point, but always have at least a `.0` in the case of an integer.

To restate slightly differently: I want Excel to do what it normally does, except if it wants to display an int, in which case it should append `.0` to it.

Some examples:

```
12.0
12.5
 0.0
 0.5368
```

Never:

```
12.500000
13
 0
```

Can Excel even do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your values are all in ColumnA, please try:

1. A Custom Format of: `[<1]0.0000;0.0`, coupled with
2. A Conditional Format formula rule of `=A1=0` with Number format and Decimal places: `1` and Applies to `=$A:$A`

or adjust the range to suit.

---

If the "arbitrary" is not a selected number of decimal places (assumed four above for numbers less than 1) but say whatever happens to be the result of a formula, then instead:

1. A Custom Format of Number, Decimal places: `1`, coupled with
2. A Conditional Format formula rule of `=AND(A1>0,A1<1)` with Format `General` and Applies to `=$A:$A`

or adjust the range to suit.

---

Re clarification of requirement:

as immediately above but change CF formula rule to:

```
=A1<>INT(A1)
```

Comment: What formula do you mean by "A Custom Format of Number, Decimal places: 1"? Do you mean "0.0"?  Would this method force -12 to display as -12.0?

Comment: Oh, I see.  But that disallows 4.37569.  The point is to get it to display the same way that Java displays a double.

Comment: Oh, but your answer inspired me and I figured it out now.  How do I award credit, then?  Can I just tell you the answer, and you can post it as your answer, and I can give you the credit?  (You really did trigger the answer for me - I hadn't considered using conditional formatting)

Comment: @Choirbean upvote and tick it as the answer that worked for you, then post your actual solution as a self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

Format the cell as General, and then use a Conditional formatting of "=MOD(A1,1)=0" to force a Decimal number with 1 place.